# preserving a session variable after session_destroy()

Tags: php, session

from my logout.php   :

```
<?php require_once("includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php
  if ( isset( $_SESSION['colony_id']))
    $cookie = $_SESSION['colony_id'] ;
  $_SESSION = array();
  if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
  }
  session_destroy();
    //this fails-  session_start() ;   
    if ( !empty($cookie))
      $_SESSION['colony_id'] = $cookie ;    
    // redirect_to("login.php?logout=1");
?>
```

I want to end the current session and then start a new session, with one of the variables from the old session in the new session. I tried adding a second session_start statement, but that had no effect. What else can I do ?

Thanks

Edit: I decided to redirect to a new page, on which a fresh session_start() statement created a new session

Comment: could just clear the session variables instead. $_SESSION = array()

Comment: In what way did adding another `session_start` hadn’t any effect? How did you test what you’ve expected? And what behavior did you expect?

Comment: I checked to see if a new session cookie was created. It was not.

Comment: @user161179: What do you mean by new session cookie? A session ID cookie with a new session ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this link :

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38042

it's a bug in php and it has a patch.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the session variable into a normal variable, and then destroy the session and put it back in the session after you create a new one.

Comment: this is what I tried, but the second_session() start statement doesn't seem to start a new session.

Answer (score 1):

If you jsut have one variable you want to save, and you absolutly want to destroy the session: 
Save the variable to a local variable, destroy the session, start a session, and then reload th session variable...

```
$localvar = $_SESSION['variable'];
session_destroy();
session_start();
$_SESSOIN['variable'] = $localvar;
```