# Unexpectedly losing session data

Tags: php, http, session, session-variables

So, I want to preserve a specific session variable after the user logs out. Like this:

```
// Save the session variable
$foo = $_SESSION["foo"];

// Terminate the session
//----------------------------------------------
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), "", time() - 3600,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

session_destroy();
session_regenerate_id();
//----------------------------------------------

// Restart the session
session_start();

// Store the variable in the session
$_SESSION["foo"] = $foo;

// Redirect the user to the same page, this time unauthenticated
header("Location: " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

But it doesn't seem to be properly stored, because after the redirect, `$_SESSION["foo"]` is null.

Can anyone help me with this? Am I doing something 'illegal' here?

NOTE:

If I do `var_dump($_SESSION["foo"])` right *before* the redirection, it does return the variable.

I always call `session_start()` before I retrieve `$_SESSION["foo"]`, of course.

Also, and I don't know if this has something to do, but `$foo` is an object, so I'm doing `$foo = unserialize($_SESSION["foo"])` and `$_SESSION["foo"] = serialize($foo);`.

Comment: You state that you are 'restarting the session', but have you ever started it? session_start() is not automagically started.

Comment: Emm not sure if I'm following. The session was previously started, I end it and then start it again with `session_start()`. I'm don't know if I can do both things in the same script, that's why I'm asking

Comment: have you output anything before calling session_start() ? that would interfere with setting the session cookie.  examine your headers.

Comment: @JohnDoe Well, the reason could be overkill? Why not just unset the sessions you don't need and (if really needed) regenerate the session id? It's seems very destructive what you are doing.

Comment: DavidChan: no I was not outputting anything (except the var_dump that I used once to check if there was anything in the variable).
@Repox I don't know, I don't think it would make a difference if I didn't regenerate the session ID. Maybe it's a bug like Michal said

Comment: @JohnDoe I just read the bug report, I agree that it would be the case in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the PHP version you use maybe this could explain the problem https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38042.

> Session destroy followed by session start appears to no longer start a new session.  The attached code works on 5.1.2 but fails on 5.1.4.

Maybe other versions may be affected as well.

This post also describes the behavior you are encountering:

- [preserving a session variable after session_destroy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632799/preserving-a-session-variable-after-session-destroy)

A possible workaround for you may be to pass the `$foo` variable to your next script as a `$_GET` argument in the location header like this:

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "?foo=" . $foo);
```

Comment: Ah this pretty much explains what is going on. It's the same exact problem I have. Thanks!

Comment: I've thought of that workaround, thing is that `$foo` is an object so I'd get pretty messy. I'll try anyways or just changing the PHP version

Comment: @Michal Begging for upvotes won't usually get you any. Let us decide from your answers if you deserve them.

Comment: @Repox - notice the `:)` after it... was just a joke ;) joking mood today... (sorry if you find it inappropriate)... btw I noticed that you agree with the answer...