# Preserving a Session Variable after session_destroy()?

Tags: php, session

I'm aware there is an identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632799/preserving-a-session-variable-after-session-destroy), but the accepted answer says it is a bug with a patch, yet the link says otherwise. The link says it is intended behaviour and not a bug.

The other answers in the question are exactly what I tried to do.

```
$variableToPreserve = $_SESSION['foo'];

session_destroy();
session_start();

// At this point in the debugger, all previous session variables are still 
// in the session anyway, making me think the session has not been destroyed yet.

$_SESSION['foo'] = $variableToPreserve;
```

Next request:

```
session_start();
// This line errors as 'foo' is not in the session.
$var = $_SESSION['foo'];
```

My only guess is that the session does not actually get destroyed until after that request has completed. The only way I can get it to preserve is by keeping all the session variables but really I need to destroy the session and only have `'foo'` set.

Comment: `foreach($_SESSION as $key => & $value) { if($key !== 'foo') unset($_SESSION[$key]); }` ? Or maybe `session_unset()` before `session_destroy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session are handeled via cookies - so (I guess) this should be the expected behaviour.

You could unset all values in the session variable manually:

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $k => $v) {
    unset($_SESSION[$k]);
}
```

instead for calling:

```
session_destroy();
session_start();
```

This would effectivly clear the session for you.

Comment: Going to accept this as it actually works. I also added `session_regenerate_id()` as the reason I'm doing this is for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code for session destroy is not like the one that provided by PHP Manual, for example:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

```
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

**YOU CAN TEST A DEMO: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/2vi-r9a**

Comment: Even with all this, it doesn't allow me to preserve the session variable I require.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out the code for you, and this is the behavior that I see.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 1;

$variableToPreserve = $_SESSION['foo'];

session_destroy();
session_start();

// At this point, the session variable is indeed destroyed, as is evident from the error that the next line throws.

echo $_SESSION['foo'];

$_SESSION['foo'] = $variableToPreserve;

echo $_SESSION['foo'];

// The above line echoes 1
```